# Why were my recent postings removed?

Tags: support

There was nothing in them that could have reasonably been considered offensive; furthermore, there was no notification about their removal.

Comment: Which recent ones?

Answer (score 8):

You were told exactly why below the posts:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

This is found in both of your deleted posts:

[image: heaviside01]
([source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/160072/25301), requires 10k+ rep)

[image]
([source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/156041/25301), requires 10k+ rep)

These are additional *thoughts* to your post. As such, they belong *in the question post* and not as **answers** to your query.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have misunderstood the communications model we use on Stack Exchange sites.

You've been using "Answer" posts to comment on or amend your questions (as if this were the USENET or a threaded-conversation forum). That's not how things work here.

Answers are reserved for *answering the question*.

To amend or extend a post please use the edit facility (modulo not changing a post beyond recognition or rendering existing answer invalid.).

Comment: Notification and reasoning would have been courteous...

Comment: @Heaviside, reading the help center and FAQ would have been courteous.